# Adding another button to the text message in "messages" in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

You know the two buttons that you get in iphone text messaging, when you click a received message(Copy|More)? Suppose I want to add one more, button there. How would I do it? I am not looking for a step by step guide. Please tell me where to start? What should I learn?

PS: I have basic ios app development knowledge.

Comment: google "iOS context menu" although you can't change it in the Messages app, only within your own app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start by having a look here at: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH13-SW1)